# Gulp using gulp-data and gulp-jade with directory

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, gulp

I have a gulp workflow with everything works well, but it seems like it only work on the uppermost file, for example: `public/index.html`, but if I would like to use `public/products/item.html`, **gulp-data** would throw an error and look for `src/json/item.json` instead of `src/json/products/item.json`.

I think there is something wrong since I used `path.basename(file.path, '.jade') + '.json')`, it will return the filename only, of course, if so, how to make it also provide the directory if it throws something like `products/item.jade`?

```
var basePath = {
    src: 'src/',
    dest: 'public/'
}

var src = {
    pages: basePath.src + 'jade/',
    json : basePath.src + 'json'
}

gulp.task('make:pages', function() {
    return gulp.src(src.pages + '**/!(_)*.jade')
        .pipe(plumber({
            errorHandler: onError
        }))
        .pipe(data(function(file) {
            return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('src/json/' + path.basename(file.path, '.jade') + '.json'));
        }))
        .pipe(jade({
            pretty: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(basePath.dest));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing I am using the same folder structure:

```
src
├── fonts
├── jade
│   ├── _layout.jade
│   ├── index.jade
│   ├── product
│   │   └── item.jade
│   ├── partials
│   │   ├── _footer.jade
│   │   └── _header.jade
├── js
├── json
│   ├── index.json
│   ├── product
│   │   └── item.json
```

I used this instead:

```
return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(file.path.replace(/jade/g, 'json')));
```

and it works! :)